# In Azure AD B2C, How do i link a social account with any existing local account during first time sign in from social login?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

When signing in with a social account, Facebook for now, I want to check if there is a local account already - using custom policies. If so the user must sign in to that so it can be linked to the social account, and failure to do so aborts social login.

If there is no local account already just create the social account and a local account with a random password as explained [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-at-signup).

There is already a stackoverflow question which is fairly similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385434/in-azure-ad-b2c-how-do-i-link-a-social-account-of-a-user-with-an-already-existi), but it always requires signing in to a local account which I do not want, and talks about "SQL identity service" which means nothing to me.

Comment: Better sample here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account, you need to combine some logic from the account linking sample, such that on detection the user also provides the credential of the existing local account for the link process to occur.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to but I fear my understanding of custom policies might not be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get this working using the TechnicalProfile from wojtekdo as a starting point and carefully reading the [MS documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/trustframeworkpolicy) on custom profiles with an eye to what I was trying to do. I also took the concept of userIdentities from the [link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account) provided in the comment by Jas Suri.

I did the merging of the social account with the local account using a subjourney simply to keep it separate from the main journey.

Note that I do not verify or ask for password for the local account. This I think acceptable since the user has already verified ownership of the email when creating the facebook account. Nevertheless, I would prefer to verify the local account and I have a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194888/azure-ad-b2c-how-to-ask-for-and-verify-password-for-local-account-during-signu) on how to do this.

TrustFrameworkExtensions xml to achieve this:

```xml
    <BuildingBlocks>
      <ClaimsSchema>
        <ClaimType Id="userIdentity">
          <DisplayName>userIdentity</DisplayName>
          <DataType>userIdentity</DataType>
          <AdminHelpText>userIdentity</AdminHelpText>
          <UserHelpText>userIdentity</UserHelpText>
        </ClaimType>
        <ClaimType Id="userIdentities">
          <DisplayName>userIdentities</DisplayName>
          <DataType>userIdentityCollection</DataType>
          <AdminHelpText>userIdentities</AdminHelpText>
          <UserHelpText>userIdentities</UserHelpText>
        </ClaimType>
        <ClaimType Id="issuers">
          <DisplayName>issuers</DisplayName>
          <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
          <UserHelpText>User identity providers. This information is received from alternativeSecurityIds</UserHelpText>
        </ClaimType>
        <ClaimType Id="signInNamesInfo.emailAddress">
          <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
          <DataType>string</DataType>
          <AdminHelpText>Email address that the user can use to sign in.</AdminHelpText>
          <UserHelpText>Email address to use for signing in.</UserHelpText>
          <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        </ClaimType>
        <ClaimType Id="emails">
          <DisplayName>Email Addresses</DisplayName>
          <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
          <AdminHelpText>Email addresses of the user.</AdminHelpText>
          <UserHelpText>Your email addresses.</UserHelpText>
        </ClaimType>
        <ClaimType Id="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
          <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
          <DataType>string</DataType>
          <AdminHelpText>Email address that the user can use for strong authentication.</AdminHelpText>
          <UserHelpText>Email address to use for strong authentication.</UserHelpText>
          <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        </ClaimType>
      </ClaimsSchema>
    
      <ClaimsTransformations>
        <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateEmailsFromOtherMailsAndSignInNamesInfo" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNamesInfo.emailAddress" TransformationClaimType="item" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
        <ClaimsTransformation Id="AddStrongAuthenticationEmailToEmails" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" TransformationClaimType="item" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
        <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
          <InputParameters>
            <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="Not supported currently. Use oid claim." />
          </InputParameters>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
        <!-- Sample: On sign-in (first time) with social account, create a userIdentity claim, using issuerUserId and issuer name -->
        <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateUserIdentity" TransformationMethod="CreateUserIdentity">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" TransformationClaimType="issuerUserId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" TransformationClaimType="issuer" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentity" TransformationClaimType="userIdentity" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
        
        <!--Sample: Add a userIdentity to the userIdentities collection. .-->
        <ClaimsTransformation Id="AppendUserIdentity" TransformationMethod="AddItemToUserIdentityCollection">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentity" TransformationClaimType="item" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentities" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentities" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
    
        <!--Sample: Extracts the list of social identity providers associated with the user -->
        <ClaimsTransformation Id="ExtractIssuers" TransformationMethod="GetIssuersFromUserIdentityCollectionTransformation">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentities" TransformationClaimType="userIdentityCollection" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuers" TransformationClaimType="issuersCollection" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
      </ClaimsTransformations>
    </BuildingBlocks>
    
    <ClaimsProviders>
      <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadCommon">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateEmailsFromOtherMailsAndSignInNamesInfo" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AddStrongAuthenticationEmailToEmails" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="logonIdentifier" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-ReadCommon" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-AssertAccountEnabledAndCreateSubjectClaimFromObjectId">
          <DisplayName>Assert account enabled</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserUpdateWithUserIdentities">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="api-version">1.6</Item>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentities" />
            <!--<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_requiresMigrationBool" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>-->
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentities" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ExtractIssuers" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
      </ClaimsProvider>
    
      <ClaimsProvider>
        <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
          <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
              <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdentity" />
              <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AppendUserIdentity" />
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
      </ClaimsProvider>
    </ClaimsProviders>
    
    <UserJourneys>
      <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
    
          <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
          <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError"/>
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>
    
          <!-- Find local account using email-->        
          <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="FindLocalAccount" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError"/>
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>
    
          <!-- start a subjourney to verify local account if one was found in previous step -->
          <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
            <Preconditions>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                <Value>objectId</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <JourneyList>
              <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="MergeWithLocalAccount" />
            </JourneyList>
          </OrchestrationStep>
    
        </OrchestrationSteps>
      </UserJourney>
    </UserJourneys>
    
    <SubJourneys>
      <SubJourney Id="MergeWithLocalAccount" Type="Call">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
          <!-- assert any found local account is enabled -->
          <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                <Value>objectId</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="AssertLocalAccountEnabled" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-AssertAccountEnabledAndCreateSubjectClaimFromObjectId"/>
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>
    
          <!-- merge account with any existing and verified local account-->
          <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                <Value>objectId</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                <Value>accountVerified</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="AADMergeAccount" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserUpdateWithUserIdentities" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>
        </OrchestrationSteps>
      </SubJourney>
    </SubJourneys>
```

I have included all the xml I added to solve the merging social and local account, excluding everything else. I am aware this is not a minimal solution and some bits are probably not needed, but it is a working solution and might help others figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was very clear to integrate it in my existing policy and works properly. Unfortunatelly for me it only works one way, so if the user signs in first with a social account and later on signs in with a local account they don't get merged. In case you have also code to achieve that, would be nice if you can share it.

Comment: Using the above sample, the merge accounts did not actually occur, should accountEnabled be used in the orchestration steps instead of accountVerified?  Otherwise, where does accountVerified get defined?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using email address as the user name you need to get that email address every time you sign in to that social provider. When you finalize the extenal provider exchange (be it Facebook) you need to take the received email address and make use of a technical profile which allows reading directory by email. There is a profile which does it but it throws an error when the account is not found so you need a slightly modified version, namely with RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist key set to false:

```
  <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="logonIdentifier" Required="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-ReadCommon" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
```

After executing the profile you will know, by checking ObjectId, if the user was found or not and act accordingly.

Comment: So I would need to add an orchestration step for this technical profile, and presumably change the Outputclaim objectId to something like existingObjectId so I can do a Precondition for that value in the next orchestration step. Also, CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID is not needed right? and what does AAD-ReadCommon do?

Comment: I don't think you need a different name. Just check the value of ObjectId. If you do other operations later on then it will be read (or created) later on and yes, CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID might not be necessary here.
AAD-ReadCommon is a base technical profile for read operations on the AAD. Different AAD-reading technical profiles include it (reading by email, by objectid, by alternative identity) - a common part of all of them (like specified protocol, some default claims etc)