# In Azure AD B2C, how can we account link automatically at sign up and sign in? User should only ever have one account

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The Azure B2C sample policies (e.g [Azure AD B2C account linkage at signup](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-at-signup)) provide a number of ways to link accounts, but they all rely on user input with regard to linking and unlinking accounts, which can be confusing. I believe a common scenario is simply wanting the user to  authenticate using whatever method they choose, and have a common experience. It should be as un-complex as feasible.

Any linking and unlinking of social accounts could be part of users' account management, but shouldn't be part of the login.

Expanding on [Azure AD B2C Auto Account Link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/auto-account-linking) the scenario would be:

**Scenario 1**

- User has previously signed up with a Local Account (bob@contoso.com)
- User logs in with Facebook, and Facebook returns the email claim - bob@contoso.com
- Facebook identity is merged into Local Account
- User is signed in
- *User is **not** invited to sign in with their Local Account*

**Scenario 2**

- User has previously signed up with Google (bob@contoso.com)
- User logs in with Facebook, and Facebook returns the email claim - bob@contoso.com
- Facebook identity is merged into Google Account
- User is signed in
- *User is **not** invited to sign in with their Google Account*

**Scenario 3**

- User has previously signed up with Google (bob@contoso.com)
- User signs up for a Local Account with bob@contoso.com (with verified email)
- Local account with password is merged into original account
- User is signed in (User can, in future sign in with local account + password)
- *User is **not** be presented with error, stating the account exists*
- *User **should not** have to perform forgot password flow*

Note that the last scenario, it is suggested that the original social account could be set up with a local account at the same time (and random password); the user would then receive a "this account already exists" error if signing up, but could do a Reset Password. But Password Reset *involves repeating exactly the same steps* as sign-up (confirm your email, provide your password).

---

(A previous question asked [How do i link a social account with any existing local account during first time sign in from social login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176128/in-azure-ad-b2c-how-do-i-link-a-social-account-with-any-existing-local-account) but did not cover local merging with social, and fails if no local account exists.)

Comment: Hi, In my case, I only want login with Google and Facebook not Local Account. Could you please enlighten some thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your version of scenario 1/2, remove steps 1-7 in the HandleLinkLocalToSocial subjourney.

Scenario 3 needs a little more work. You need to detect if the account exists first, then write the account without throwing an error if it already exists.

The reason I made account linking as per the sample, is to prevent hijacking someone’s account, eg they have Google with MFA, but Facebook with weak password. User sign up with Google but attacker hijacks the account using login with their Facebook. User thought it was secure since they used 2FA for Google but forgot their FB login was weak.

Comment: Thank you and yes I agree there are different levels of security for different scenarios. I have implemented your "Azure AD B2C account linkage" sample, and added a Google provider successfully too; I then removed the steps as you suggested. Everything works perfectly for Scenario 1 & 2 (although there is an obvious error that needs fixing here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/b2acbcfef213413be8747caae98482883a556bca/policies/auto-account-linking/policy/AccountLinkExtensions.xml#L721) - I will attempt Scenario 3 but suspect it is complex.

Comment: I kept the key name the same as Facebook to be compatible with quick-deploy function. Will mention it in the readme to update these key names appropriately.

Comment: I see, thank you. Regarding step 3 (merging a local sign up into an existing account) - if I ensure <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">True</Item> is set, then that would satisfy the requirement of being sure the user is who they say they are. So what I have tried is setting RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists to false in the AAD-UserWriteUsingUserIdentity profile, but it still returns the "user with the specified ID already exists" error.

Comment: In fact, I was nearly correct. The key is to set RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists to false on the AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail technical profile. I will write up a fuller answer and link to the updated AccountLinkExtensions.xml

Comment: Yes but if you update it directly there, all users can sign up again… so you want to make a copy and only call your new version if {account exists and extension_haspassword=false}.

Comment: Thank you , good point. However, consider this scenario - user signs up and uses app, comes back 3 months later, forgets they've signed up, and goes through sign up again (verified email). This is remarkably common for some apps. I think it can be argued that it is bad experience to tell them they've already got an account, and push them through the whole forgot-password flow, where they're largely just repeating the same steps as signing up anyway. Others may see it differently, I but can't detect any security issues allowing account overwriting if email is verified.

Comment: Definitely ok to do!

Comment: Scenario 3 is something I would like to implement. Do you have any working sample? Can I safely merge local account identity into existing social account userIdentities (so the objectId does not change) or should it be handled in some other way?